# Change permalinks of 'post' type (add_rewrite_rule or ?????)

Tags: permalinks

I added Hierarchy (to choose PARENT of post) with custom coding ([several lines plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/add-hierarchy-parent-to-post/)).
Now, but the permalinks of posts are still:

```
example.com/post-slug
```

i want them to be:

```
example.com/parent-post-slug/this-post-slug
```

Which function to use? I am not well aware of them (`add_rewrite_url`,`add_permastructure` or etc..)

Comment: `Pages` have that option by default, can't you use `pages` with hierarchy instead of `posts` with hierarchy? `Post` hierarchy in WordPress is by default based on `Category`. Making changes to that is definitely possible, but my suggestion is to use `Pages` for that purpose.

Comment: @Fayaz thanks, but in this case i exactly need posts..

Comment: OK, so basically you need the same rewrite rules that already exist for `pages` to be applied to `posts`. Can you please add your CODE for applying the hierarchy for `posts` within your question? Rewrite rule may depend on that CODE.

Comment: I use this plugin - https://wordpress.org/plugins/add-hierarchy-parent-to-post/